# How to bind multiple commands to one key with mpv

Tags: windows, mpv

Is it possible to show the commands `show-text ${media-title}`, `show-progress` and `show-text ${playlist}` on separate lines each with a single key bind?
If i enter `MENU show-text "${media-title} ${duration}"` in the input.conf file, it will show both commands, but when i enter `MENU show-progress; show-text "${media-title}"` for example it will not show the first command.
Also this command `ENTER cycle pause; show-progress`, only shows the progress info on play from a paused state, not when the video is paused.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for...?

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/input.rst#synchronous-vs-asynchronous

Quote:

> The async and sync prefix matter only for how the issuer of the
>   command waits on the completion of the command. Normally it does not
>   affect how the command behaves by itself. There are the following
>   cases:
>
> - Normal input.conf commands are always run asynchronously. Slow running commands are queued up or run in parallel.
> - "Multi" input.conf commands (1 key binding, concatenated with ;) will be executed in order, except for commands that are async (either
>     prefixed with async, or async by default for some commands). The async
>     commands are run in a detached manner, possibly in parallel to the
>     remaining sync commands in the list.
> - ...